# What percent of cats are 'lap cats'?

Tags: cats, behavior

My male ginger tabby cat just loves to come curl and sleep on my lap while I work on my desktop which is heart-warming most of the time. 
But I've read that many cats prefer to stay/sleep at a certain distance from their owners.
So I'm wondering how common is this lap-loving behavior among cats? Is it more prevalent among certain cat breeds?

Answer (score 7):

I doubt anyone's actually bothered to actually figure out numbers on it, but it's certainly a common enough behavior that even people that have never owned a cat are aware cats do this. The other thing about sitting on laps is that it's partially a learned behavior. Cats that want to be near humans are obviously going to be more predisposed to it, but they might also decide the better place is next to the human, or top of their keyboard, or wherever.  Or they might be encouraged by a human to do it when it wasn't their first choice.

Sitting on laps definitely seems to be more common among certain breeds, as people commonly make lists of cuddly cat breeds, and certain breeds are just about always on it. Some of the breeds that are commonly mentioned, but by no means exclusively, are the Ragdoll, the Scottish Fold, the Rex, the Siamese and it's cousins the Burmese and Tonkinese, the Maine Coon, the Persian, and the Sphynx.

Comment: Persian and Maine Coon are lap cats too?!